# Nature Of Bulb Glowing In Parallel LR circuit with bulbs

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electricity

> In the given circuit the switch is initially closed and then opened after some considerable time.Then which bulb  will stop glowing first? Which bulb will glow more brightly?Why ? 
>   .After opening which bulb will glow more brightly? Which one will stop glowing first? Why ?

I am a bit confused because my teacher said that the bulb connected with resistor will switch off immediately.But won't the inductor act as a source of EMF after the switch is opened ?

P.S:Consider that the back emf of the inductor is NOT NEGLIGIBLE
[problem http://www.alfaphysics.co.in/misconceptions/electromagnetic_induction_files/image016.gif](http://www.alfaphysics.co.in/misconceptions/electromagnetic_induction_files/image016.gif)

Comment: Your image has disappeared.  The question is incomprehensible without it.  Please can you provide a new link to the image.

Answer (score 0):

When the *ideal* switch is opened the circuit comes series circuit. When in series, the instantaneous current $i(t)$ will be same through all the components. Now the voltage over the bulbs are exactly same in *ideal* world if the bulbs resistances are same i.e. $R_{B1}(t) = R_{B2}(t)$. In this series circuit the instantaneous current is
$$ i(t) = I_0\exp(-\frac{R_{B1}+R_{B2}+R}{L}t)$$ 
So in ideal world i can't see why the lower bulb would switch off. Both bulbs would stop glowing at the same time because they are affected by the same current. Also they would glow equally bright all the time.

Comment: You've ignored the resistor R in series with B2 in the steady state.  In the steady state, I would expect B1 to be brighter than B2, unless the resistance of L equals that of R.  If the switch is turned off, then I would expect B1 to remain lit for longer simply because it was already hotter when the switch was turned off.

Comment: Try solving for voltages rather than currents, and keep in mind the phase shift across the inductor.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. My answer focuses only on the situation, where the switch has been opened, and not on the steady state situation where the switch is closed.

Comment: You seems to assume same current implies same bright. But isn't dissipated power which will influence on the bright? Thus bulb with more resistance will dissipate more power and then it will glow more.

Comment: @Simon B I agree with you.Thanks.That one sentence of yours cleared a lot of my confusion.